# Why pstack is much faster than gdb with just attaching, saving stacks and quitting?

Tags: linux, shell, gdb, stack-trace, pstack

I have a script, which runs gdb with command file like this:

```
set logging file file_name
set logging on
thread apply all bt
q
y
```

Why pstack is much faster than this script? Can I achive that fastness with gdb somehow?

EDIT: The difference was gdb versions. I used gdb-7.10, and it took about 14 sec to dump stack traces. with gdb 7.0.1, which pstack used, it took 2 sec. Most of time went for gdb-7.10 on loading symbols from our lib, and I couldn't found the appropriate option for `-readnever` in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system at least `pstack` is a shell script that runs gdb, so you can probably see exactly what is being run by just looking in the `pstack` executable.

I suspect that the interesting part of the script might well be:

```
set width 0
set height 0
set pagination no
```

Actually `set pagination no` is the same as `set height 0`, so you can forget the `set pagination no` part.

The `set height 0` and `set width 0` turn off any attempt by gdb to display the output wrapped to your terminal width, and presented page at a time.

I expect that this wrapping, and page at a time output, causes a lot of additional processing everytime gdb prints anything.

There's not much else in the `pstack` script that is different to your script, so I don't see what else it could be.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try.

Comment: Ah yes, really it uses gdb. I thought gdb uses pstack and does a lot of other work, thanks.

Comment: Well, the reason wasn't that. The difference was gdb versions. I used gdb-7.10, and it took about 14 sec to dump stack traces. with gdb 7.0.1, which pstack used, it took 2 sec. Most of time went for gdb-7.10 on loading symbols from our lib. Something here: https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2004-11/msg00227.html

Comment: But I couldn't find how to disable it in the new version.

Comment: I'm going to guess your base distro is old-ish and you upgraded gdb.  Older RH gdbs had the `-readnever` hack precisely to speed up `pstack`.  However, later on, we added `.gdb_index` support, and this sped up symbol reading enough that `-readnever` was no longer deemed necessary.  An older distro won't have those indices, though.